# ffmpeg concat doesn't sync to manual frame by frame concatenation

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have hundreds of short (10-120seconds) videos (H264 mp4) with audio (aac). (let's call these 'clips'). All identical video and audio codecs, resolution, framerate, crf, pixel format, sample rate etc.

**concat_demux:**

If I concat these with **ffmpeg concat (demuxer)**, I get a single nice H264 mp4 with **audio perfectly synced to the video** (as expected).

```
cmd_args = ['ffmpeg',
            '-f concat',
            '-safe 0',
            f'-i "{output_filelist_path}"',
            '-c copy',
            '-y',
            '-r 30', # trying this out of desperation
            f'"{output_concat_demux}"'
            ]

cmd = ' '.join(cmd_args)
r = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, cwd=args.output_dir)
```

**frame_by_frame:**

However, if I manually iterate every frame of every clip video and write the frames to an mp4 using skvideo.io, this video drifts out of sync with the concat_demux version.

```
input_dict = { '-r':str(fps) } 
output_dict = { '-r':str(fps), '-pix_fmt':'yuv420p', '-vcodec':'libx264', '-crf':'18' }
video_writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter(output_path, inputdict=input_dict, outputdict=output_dict) 

for video_path in video_paths:
   video = skvideo.io.vread(video_path) # read all frames into np.array
   for frame in video:
      video_writer.writeFrame(frame)
video_writer.close()
```

When I compare these two files in a video editor (e.g. AfterEffects) and step through frame by frame, I can see that with every new clip, the frame_by_frame version slips 1 or 2 frames *ahead* of the ffmpeg concat_demux version. What is going on? How can I fix - or at least debug - this?

On a side note, I do need to concatenate manually frame by frame, as I'm also doing a ton of other stuff (triggering events on clip change, overlaying additional elements etc). And I need to be able to sync a concatenated audio. I was hoping to concatenate the video manually frame by frame and do my post-processing, and then mux with the audio from the ffmpeg concat_demux version. But alas they drift out of sync.

---

(I've found quite a few posts on SO where the problem is using ffmpeg concat results in videos which are out of sync with the audio. However, this is not my problem. My video created with ffmpeg concat is perfectly in sync with the audio, but it's out of sync with a manually frame-by-frame concatenated video.)

---

**Update - concat_protocol**

I've tried using the concat protocol. Now the output of this gives a file where the video is frame synced to the frame_by_frame version, BUT the audio is synced to the audio of the concat_demux version. So its audio is out of sync with the video.

```
intermediate_paths = []
for p in clip_file_list:
    intermediate_path = os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'intermediate', os.path.basename(p) + '.ts')
    intermediate_paths.append(intermediate_path)
    cmd_args = ['ffmpeg',
        f'-i "{p}"',
        '-c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y',
        f'"{intermediate_path}"'
        ]

    cmd = ' '.join(cmd_args)
    r = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, cwd=args.output_dir)


intermediate_paths = '|'.join(intermediate_paths)
cmd_args = ['ffmpeg',
            f'-i "concat:{intermediate_paths}"',
            '-c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc',
            f'"{output_concat_path}"'
            ]

cmd = ' '.join(cmd_args)
r = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, cwd=args.output_dir)
```

I am getting loads of errors like below

```
    corrupt input packet in stream 0
[mp4 @ 0x137e043d0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 83027966, current: 83027198; changing to 83027967. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

---

here's the info on the two output files. Input #0 is the ffmpeg concat_demux. Input #1 is the manual frame-by-frame. Note the concat.mp4 has a framerate of 29.94 fps. I'm not sure if this is the problem. I couldn't figure out how to make this 30 (see '-r 30' in the ffmpeg concat command above)

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clips_concat.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:01:43.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5412 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 5276 kb/s, 29.94 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clips_frames.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:01:43.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4917 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080, 4914 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

---

here's info on first few clips (the manual concat is already 2 frames out of sync with the ffmpeg concat version by the second clip!)

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3944 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 3818 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4557 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 4438 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5447 kb/s
  Stream #2:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 5320 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #2:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5978 kb/s
  Stream #3:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 5851 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #3:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:16.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6570 kb/s
  Stream #4:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 6441 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #4:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:13.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5069 kb/s
  Stream #5:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 4940 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #5:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_6.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:22.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4775 kb/s
  Stream #6:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 4642 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #6:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'clip_1080px_7.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:22.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5402 kb/s
  Stream #7:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 5269 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #7:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing `29.94 fps` and `30 fps`. I think you should remove `'-r 30', # trying this out of desperation`. What is the framerate of the input clips, 29.94fps or 30fps? Why do you want to change the framerate from 29.94fps to 30fps? For debugging the issue you may use FFprobe with `-show_frames` and/or with `-show_packets`, check the timestamps and the packet duration.

Comment: all of the input clips are 30fps (you can see this in ffmpeg output above). I don't know why the ffmpeg concat_demux video is coming out at 29.94 fps, since all of the inputs are 30fps. Adding or removing -r 30 in the concat demux command has no effect. Same output.